# Modifiying the CollectionViewSource SortParameter Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I am currently implementing a CAN Monitor which follows MVVM style coding. 
It has various headers such as ID, TimeStamp, Direction...
The logging function is designed for more than 50000 lines of tracing and hence sorting via OrderBy function is too slow for me. Also iterating and adding every new message at the right position is also not feasible.

Right now I have designed the Sort via **CollectionViewSource**. But the issue is that I can only decide on one parameter at a time. I require dynamic changes to the sort parameter based on user clicks on the header.

```
<CollectionViewSource IsLiveSortingRequested="True" x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding MonitorList}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName= "CanCobIdString" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

.
.
.

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl_Monitor" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}, UpdateSourceTrigger =PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CanMessageTemplate2}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true"
```

I tried Binding the PropertyName but I believe this is not the right way. Is there some other way I can change the PropertyName based on User Clicks. (I just need to be able to change the PropertyName string at runtime)